# UIApplication.shared.delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext is nil?

Tags: swift, core-data

I am in the process of adding core data to my app.  I'm using exactly the same code as I used in a test app with the exact same schema, yet I'm getting different results.

```
var context: NSManagedObjectContext!
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

is the code I use to set up in my VC, yet context is nil after this in my actual app.  Furthermore, if I look inside appDelegate with the debugger, in my large app persistentContainer.storage is nil, but in the test app I can look inside of it and see props such as _viewContext.  I fear I may have missed something when going through the steps to add core data to an already created app.  Any idea what my problem could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the name of your NSPersistentContainer in appDelegate.This might be giving you the nil value for the context

Answer (score 0):

When I use CoreData, I set the context as:

context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext.

I just followed a tutorial. Maybe you can try it... ;)